# How to preserve state of home page while click on home link

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having one scenario.

I have an app using reactjs, where let say I am on home page and there I have selected some checkbox or may be some item from drop down. Now from home page I am navigating to other page.

If I come back from other page by pressing browser back button then I am getting my selected item on home page. But if I click on home button to go to home page then the selected Item gone and default item is showing on home page. I mean page got refreshed with default data.

But my task is to keep the selected item when coming back from other page after clicking home button.

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to save it in session storage or local storage

Answer (score 1):

In React, state is reset to the default values anytime you mount the component. This happens when you leave and come back to the page.

The most "React" way to solve the issue would be to use context. I would recommend reading [this react guide](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) if you want to learn how to implement context in your app. It will continue to store state when you navigate between pages of your app.

The downside to context is that it resets if you reload your browser. If that will be an issue, I'd recommend using local storage, assuming that you are storing some lightweight values. Let me know if that makes sense!